# How to show query count value in overall common header notification using codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I call out the header in each view page. And I want to show overall count value in common header. But the problem I have is I don't have the controllers and models for the header. Because the header is used as a common. So, Can I use the count value for each page in the header?

I used hook function for Codeigniter but it only showed at the top of the page. I can't call out the return value in the header view.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is bit fuzzy but i think you want this:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
echo $CI->db->total_queries();
```